# PHP number_format not working

Tags: php

I'm making a website and I've got the following problem.
I'm importing query's from MySql, but to make it easier to understand I'm using local arrays now.

```
<?php 
            $productnames = array("Raspatat oorlog", "Raspatat mayo", "Raspatat pizza", "Raspatat ui", "Raspatat curry");
            $productprices = array(1.7, 2.3, 2.45, 3.45, 34.669);

            echo "<table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product</td>
                        <td>Prijs</td>
                    </tr>";
            for($i =0; $i < sizeof($productnames); $i++) {
                $iprice = number_format((float)$pruductprices[$i], 2, ',', '');
                echo "<tr><td>$productnames[$i]</td>
                <td>$iprice</td></tr>"; 
            }

            echo "</table>";
            echo $iprice;
        ?>
```

The code is running, but in my table i get a price of 0,00 everywhere.
Does anyone know why?

Thanks!

(this is the table

```
Product         Prijs
Raspatat oorlog |0,00
Raspatat mayo   |0,00
Raspatat pizza  |0,00
Raspatat ui     |0,00
Raspatat curry  |0,00
```

}

Comment: Damn. Now I want to eat raspatat for lunch :(

Comment: @PeeHaa Dammit, The wiki entry for raspatat is only available in the .nl version! What is it? It looks like some sort of deep-fried potato/pasta/something that looks really nice?

Comment: @Fluffeh Think french fries only made with mashed potatoes instead. Damn tasty. If you ever come ever here to grab a beer we will get it :)

Comment: @PeeHaa Careful hehe, I might just take you up on that one day. After translating a few pages, it sounds very interesting. Maybe with a pork knuckle and sauerkraut or some baked fish?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a typo in your code (around your variable `pruductprices` name):

```
<?php 
    $productnames = array("Raspatat oorlog", "Raspatat mayo", "Raspatat pizza", "Raspatat ui", "Raspatat curry");
    $productprices = array(1.7, 2.3, 2.45, 3.45, 34.669);

    echo "<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Prijs</td>
    </tr>";
    for($i =0; $i < sizeof($productnames); $i++) 
    {
        $iprice = number_format((float)$productprices[$i], 2, ',', '');
        echo "<tr><td>$productnames[$i]</td>
        <td>$iprice</td></tr>"; 
    }

    echo "</table>";
    echo $iprice;
?>
```

Output:

```
 Product    Prijs
Raspatat oorlog     1,70
Raspatat mayo   2,30
Raspatat pizza  2,45
Raspatat ui     3,45
Raspatat curry  34,67
34,67
```

If you want to easily debug a script, add this to the top:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

It will show you all the whoopsie-daisies and makes for debugging bliss.

Comment: thanks!! I have red the code over and over and been looking for answers on internet the whole time. Sorry :p

Comment: @RikNijhuis Yeah, just a suggestion - turn on all warnings/errors when writing code. The first thing I saw when I ran your code was `Undefined variable: pruductprices in /var/www/test.php on line 12` - which sort of makes is damn easy :)

Comment: I just switched to Adobe Dreamweaver so I haven't really looked at the settings yet. Well I will do now. Thanks for yout suggestion.

Comment: @RikNijhuis Adobe Dreamweaver? ****twitch**** really ****twitch****? Do yourself a favour and get into Eclipse PDT!

Answer (score 3):

You wrote 'pruductprices' - change it to `$productprices` and it works.

Seems you need some more [error reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.error-reporting.php) for your development.